# Safari’s dev tools reflecting incorrect css value

Tags: css, safari

I’m attempting to get a select drop-down to look the same in Safari as it does in Chrome and Firefox, and I’m encountering something that’s difficult for me to understand. One of the issues is that the border radius is not the same. It should be 30px, but it’s showing with 5px. When I inspect the element, I’m seeing that my CSS rule is present and the default of 5px is being overwritten. However, what I see on the screen clearly is a 5px border radius.

Stranger still, when I look at the computed values, it shows 5px for each corner of the element. When I click on where that style is coming from, I am taken to my rule of 30px.

Is Safari just really awful at displaying the accurate CSS, or is something else at play here?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I had some similar experiences and I found safari really tribble and awful. but I hope your problem has had a suitable answer.

Comment: "Safari ignores border-radius on <select> elements unless -webkit-appearance is overridden to an appropriate value." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius

Comment: Ugh. I was afraid of something like this, but now I know.

Comment: It's just some additional code you'll need to add. A little extra work for you courtesy of good ol' Apple ;)